# What is this interface and why this drains my battery?

Tags: wifi, network-interface, power-management, laptop, battery

```
$ ip address 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:fa:9b:2c:ba:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:fd:d1:8e:b6:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.120/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 4376sec preferred_lft 4376sec
    inet6 fe80::ee8:c6d6:d9a5:cffc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
powertop

The battery reports a discharge rate of 6.15 W
The energy consumed was 126 J
The estimated remaining time is 2 hours, 53 minutes

Summary: 981.3 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 71.4% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  2.89 W      0.0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: enp0s31f6 (e1000e)
  2.18 W     10.6%                      Device         Display backlight
  368 mW      2.0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlp3s0 (iwlwifi)
  118 mW    212.6 ms/s      37.8        kWork          intel_atomic_commit_work
 48.0 mW     86.5 ms/s       1.0        Process        [PID 5241] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 41.8 mW     75.4 ms/s       0.9        Process        [PID 1436248] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 19.0 mW     34.1 ms/s       0.9        Process        [PID 5322] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 16.9 mW     30.5 ms/s       0.6        Process        [PID 5324] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 13.4 mW     19.0 ms/s       0.7        Process        [PID 1736] picom -b
 7.83 mW     12.5 ms/s       5.6        Process        [PID 1453] /usr/lib/Xorg :0 -seat seat
 7.57 mW     13.6 ms/s       3.4        Process        [PID 5193] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 6.51 mW     11.7 ms/s      0.25        Process        [PID 5321] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 5.84 mW     10.4 ms/s       0.7        Process        [PID 1849] /usr/lib/xfce4/panel/wrappe
 5.43 mW      9.8 ms/s       1.4        Process        [PID 5254] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 4.93 mW      8.9 ms/s      18.9        Interrupt      [9] acpi
 4.73 mW      8.5 ms/s     341.4        Timer          tick_sched_timer
 4.46 mW      8.0 ms/s       0.6        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
 4.15 mW      7.5 ms/s       1.0        Process        [PID 5119] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 3.57 mW      6.4 ms/s       0.3        Process        [PID 5145] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 3.22 mW      3.3 ms/s       0.5        Process        [PID 5226] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 2.25 mW      4.1 ms/s      0.00        Process        [PID 1429341] [kworker/0:1]
 1.80 mW      3.3 ms/s      0.15        kWork          wb_workfn
 1.78 mW      3.2 ms/s       3.3        Interrupt      [9] RCU(softirq)
 1.67 mW      3.0 ms/s      0.25        Process        [PID 506] /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/aut
 1.52 mW      2.7 ms/s      23.4        Interrupt      [158] i915
 1.39 mW      2.5 ms/s      0.25        Process        [PID 1845] /usr/lib/xfce4/panel/wrappe
 1.37 mW      2.5 ms/s      0.20        Process        [PID 1842] /usr/lib/xfce4/panel/wrappe
 1.28 mW      2.3 ms/s       0.5        Process        [PID 5154] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 1.24 mW      2.2 ms/s      15.3        Interrupt      [0] HI_SOFTIRQ
 1.23 mW    351.8 us/s       0.5        Process        [PID 1442099] awk
 1.23 mW      2.2 ms/s     349.4        kWork          dbs_work_handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jordanm mentioned, it is an ethernet port.

Here is the naming convention for ports:

```
enp4s10f1                        pci 0000:04:0a.1
| | |  |                                |  |  | |
| | |  |                   domain <- 0000  |  | |
| | |  |                                   |  | |
en| |  |  --> ethernet                     |  | |
  | |  |                                   |  | |
  p4|  |  --> prefix/bus number (4)   <-- 04  | |
    |  |                                      | |
    s10|  --> slot/device number (10) <--    10 |
       |                                        |
       f1 --> function number (1)     <--       1
```

You are experiencing what we in the networking world call a "disabled" or "deactivated" port. As you can see here `state DOWN`, the port is still physically available and drawing power, but is forbidden to pass traffic at the software level. Unfortunately in linux the only way to totally turn off the port would be to remove the driver for that port. In this case, the amount of power that is drawn on an unused port is very minimal, so it would not be worth your time to go though the process of attempting to power it off completely.